# Connecting to MySQL using Java on Debian

Tags: java, mysql, debian

I am trying to connect to MySQL database with Java and I get the following error:

```
SQLException: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '????????????????' at line 1
```

I cannot understand the error and searched a lot on the web but did not found anything. This is the code I am using:

```
    try
    {
        Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver").newInstance();
    }
    catch (Exception E)
    {
        System.err.println("Unable to load driver");
        E.printStackTrace();
    }

    try
    {
        Connection C = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://127.0.0.1:3306/DATABASE_NAME","USERNAME","PASSWORD");
        Statement Stmt = C.createStatement();

        ResultSet RS = Stmt.executeQuery("SELECT somefield FROM sometable");

        while (RS.next())
        {
             System.out.print("\"" + RS.getString(1) + "\"");
             System.out.print(" by " + RS.getString(2));
             System.out.println(": " + RS.getString(3));
        }
        C.close();
        RS.close();
        Stmt.close();
    }
    catch (SQLException E)
    {
        System.out.println("SQLException: " + E.getMessage());
        System.out.println("SQLState:     " + E.getSQLState());
        System.out.println("VendorError:  " + E.getErrorCode());
    }
```

The SQL query above is an example for the question. The one I am using works without any problem in MySQL console. In fact, even if I remove the query and the statement from the code above, I still get the same error.
Can someone help?
Thanks in advance

Comment: What line is the exception being thrown from (in your catch, add a E.printStackTrace())?  Also, try throwing a semicolon at the end of the query, e.g. "select field from table;"

Comment: Hi, thanks for your comment, I also tried adding a semicolon but no difference in the error

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Most likely it's because you're using 
select field from table- table is a SQL reserved word. If you want to do this query, you'll probably need to do

```
select field from `table`
```

with the word table in back ticks.

Comment: Sorry for the misunderstanding, I should clarify this before. The SQL query above is an generic example I put on the question and not the one I am actually using. The query I am using is correct. At least when I execute it directly in MySQL console it works correctly. In fact, even if I remove the query and the statement from the Java Code, I still get the same error.

Comment: I've seen this occasionally when the java client is sending requests in a different character set than the server expects, for example, the server wants EUC-JP characters and you're sending US-ASCII... that would also match the '???????????' that you post in the error message.

Comment: Finally, this worked! It was an encoding problem indeed. I just used encoding set "latin1" and this just made my day. Many thanks to @Dataknife, I would't really imagine that encoding would be a problem.